# Mark OSGI Event As Handled

Tags: java, osgi

When I register event handlers to OSGI, I technically register services, which might or might not have a ranking. So since there is a fix order in which the event handlers are executed, I want to be able to tell all successive events that the event was already handled and they should not execute.

What I want is similar to AWT's `consume()` method on some of the events, or SWT's `doit` flag.

There's nothing like that on the OSGI event, and I can't change the properties of the `Event` in the `handleEvent()` method to just add my own property.

Is there a elegant solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not the intention of the Event Admin service. Every handler is supposed to receive the same event; this is why the content of the event is immutable.